# Display specific html tags in webview from wordpress website

Tags: java, android, json, wordpress, webview

I'm trying to develop an android app in order to display articles (in different sections) from my wordpress site and with the same site style. So I tried JSON-API plugin and I noticed that I cannot display articles as I would like to do. So I'm now thinking to work with webview and I'm wondering if there is a way to select only a div or a container (the one in wich there's the article list) in the web page bypassing header, footer and the other stuff. I tried to search for some examples but I couldn't find anything helpful. 
Do you have examples/suggestions? I'm stuck since days and I can't find a solution.

Comment: you can easily extract html, but then you'll have to mod any applicable css to handle the new structure. e.g. if you have a selector `body div.foo span.bar` and you rip out/display only `span.bar`, then the selector won't match anymore and you get a "different" view.

Comment: How can I extract a specific tag?